# Could someone help for connecting to sql server in Java (vaadin)

Tags: java, sql-server, vaadin, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Could someone help for connecting to SQLserver in Java (Vaadin)

Hello Folks .. 
I am very much new to Java ,, I do not know how to connect to SQLsever, I have written a code but it's stating that resources not available.

```
    HorizontalLayout hor = new HorizontalLayout();
    //hor.setSizeFull();

    HorizontalLayout hor2 = new HorizontalLayout();
    //hor.setSizeFull();
    try {
        JDBCConnectionPool pool = new SimpleJDBCConnectionPool("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver",
                "SERVEUR", "SA", "");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        content.addComponent(new Label("test"));
        Logger.getLogger(MyVaadinUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this. Hope it will help you..
https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/sqlcontainer.html